# Regex validation of operators in conditional statements

Tags: c#, regex

I've built a dynamic conditional validator in C# that can validate if a condition written in a textbox input is true or false.

```
string a = "25 > 20";
bool aResult = ValidateInput(a); // Will generate true

string b = "10 != 10";
bool bResult = ValidateInput(b); // Will generate false
```

Now im stuck at validating the input which comes from a textbox, Im thinking regex but dont know where to start really.

The valid conditionals are

```
=   ==   <   >   <=   >=   !=
```

Any advice is highly appreciated

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a third party libray like [Flee](http://flee.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=GettingStarted&referringTitle=Examples) to evaluate your expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can split the string based on your operators and then perform the validation.

A quick and dirty code sample in LinqPad:

```
void Main()
{
    string a = "25 > 20";

    string b = "10 != 10";


    var splits = a.Split(new string[]{}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    splits.Dump();


    var result = Validate(splits);
    result.Dump();

    splits = b.Split(new string[]{}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    splits.Dump();
    result = Validate (splits);

    result.Dump();
}

// Define other methods and classes here

bool Validate(string[] input)
{
var op = input[1];
switch(op)
    {
    case ">":
    return int.Parse(input[0]) > int.Parse(input[2]);
    case "!=":
    return int.Parse(input[0]) != int.Parse(input[2]);
    }
    return false;
}
```

You can easily customize this a lot if you want to.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you only allow integers on each side of the conditional, something like this should work:

```
^\s*\d+\s*(?:==?|<=?|>=?|!=)\s*\d+\s*$
```

The `\s*` all over the place is to make this very tolerant of extra whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

```
^\d+\s*(>=|<|>|<=|=|==|!=|<>)\s*\d+$
```